# В wordpress 5 пустой @_POST во время событий сохранения

Tags: wordpress, post

Добавил на страницу редактирования поста метабокс с произвольными полями как описано [здесь](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/).
Блок исправно появляется и при сохранении поста срабатывает хук для сохранения полей из метабокса. Проблема в том, что $_POST абсолютно пустой. Пробовал менять событие save_post на другие: pre_post_update, wp_insert_post_data и другие, но везде одно и тоже. Разве что pre_post_update принимает аргумент в виде данных для сохранения поста, но среди них нет метаполей. Перерыл разные источники в интернете с примерами, но везде одно и тоже - ловим в хуке массив POST и используем как хотим. В чём может быть причина пустого $_POST?

Мой код -

```
function wporg_add_custom_box(){
    add_meta_box(
        'wporg_box_id',          
        'Custom Meta Box Title',
        'wporg_custom_box_html',
        'post'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wporg_add_custom_box');

function wporg_custom_box_html($post){
    ?>
    <label for="wporg_field">Description for this field</label>
    <select name="wporg_field" id="wporg_field" class="postbox">
        <option value="">Select something...</option>
        <option value="something">Something</option>
        <option value="else">Else</option>
    </select>
    <?php
}

function wporg_save_postdata($post_id){
    if (array_key_exists('wporg_field', $_POST)) {
        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            '_wporg_meta_key',
            $_POST['wporg_field']
        );
    }

    ob_start();
    var_dump($_POST);
    $result = ob_get_clean();
    $fp = fopen('log.txt', "a");
    fwrite($fp, $result.'---');
    fclose($fp);
}
add_action('save_post', 'wporg_save_postdata');
```

Comment: на save_post сделай var_dump( $_POST ); exit(); и сохрани пост. Посмотри что там будет

Comment: Зачем нам читать документацию? Примеры в ней правильные и рабочие. Вы свой код покажите в виде минимального, воспроизводимого примера.

Comment: Если просто распечатать и записать в логе $_POST, то "array(0) {}" (в логе). А если с exit();, то к этому добавиться надпись в админке об ошибке сохранения, что логично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код работает, см. скриншот с отладчиком

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы не там смотрите файл. Дело в том, что в ядре, в плагинах, в теме, стоят хуки на save_post. Все они срабатывают, создавая файлы log.txt в разных папках, причём с разным выводом. Задайте абсолютный путь файла log.txt, пишите его в режиме append, и вы увидите результат. А лучше, пользуйтесь современной IDE с отладчиком.

Comment: Спасибо, это мне помогло. Я знал, что вордпресс несколько раз вызывает функцию сохранения, но не ожидал, что в нескольких файлах и в разных каталогах. По поводу IDE, приму к сведению и обязательно опробую.